# Append Option Select Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I have 3 dependent option selects and I'm trying **to populate depending on previous selection with AJAX** but I can't.

I'm using Laravel and this part seems to be ok.

**HTML :**

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
    {!! Form::label('country', 'Seleccione el País') !!}</br>

    <select name="country" id="country" class="form-control country" >
        <option value=""  disabled selected>Paises</option>
        @foreach($countries as $country)
           <option value="{{$country->id}}">{{$country->name}}</option>
        @endforeach  
   </select>
</div>


<div class="form-group col-md-3">
    {!! Form::label('prov', 'Seleccione la Provincia') !!}</br>

    <select name="province" id="province" class="form-control province">    
        <option value=""  disabled>Provincias</option>
    </select> 
</div>


<div class="form-group col-md-3">
    {!! Form::label('county', 'Seleccione el Partido') !!}</br>
    <select class="form-control" name="county" id="county">
        <option value=""  disabled >Partido</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-3">
    {!! Form::label('locality', 'Seleccione la Localidad') !!}</br>
    <select class="form-control" name="locality" id="locality">
        <option value=""  disabled >Localidad</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**JS :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

$(document).on('change','.country',function(){
     //console.log("hmm its change");

    var country_id=$(this).val();
    // console.log(country_id);
    var select=$(this).parent();
     console.log(select);
    var op=" ";

    $.ajax({
        type:'get',
        url:'{{ URL::route('findProvince') }}',
        data:{'id':country_id},
        success:function(data){
            //console.log(url);

            //console.log(data);

            //console.log(data.length);
            op+='<option value="0" selected disabled>Selecciona La Provincia</option>';
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            op+='<option value="'+data[i].id+'">'+data[i].name+'</option>';
            //console.log(op);
           }

           select.find('.province').html(" ");
           select.find('.province').append(op);
           //console.log(op);

        },
        error:function(){

        }
    });
});
});

</script>
```

I guess that the problem is in `select.find`, because I can see the correct response in `console.log(op)`.

This is the **op data**:

```
 <option value="0" selected disabled>Selecciona La Provincia</option>
 <option value="1">Buenos Aires</option>
 <option value="2">Catamarca</option> 
 <option value="3">Chaco</option>
 <option value="4">Chubut</option>
 <option value="5">Córdoba</option>
 <option value="6">Corrientes</option>
 <option value="7">Entre Ríos</option>
 <option value="8">Formosa</option>
 <option value="9">Jujuy</option>
 <option value="10">La Pampa</option>
 <option value="11">La Rioja</option>
 <option value="12">Mendoza</option>
 <option value="13">Misiones</option>
 <option value="14">Neuquén</option>
 <option value="15">Río Negro</option>
 <option value="16">Salta</option>
 <option value="17">San Juan</option>
 <option value="18">San Luis</option>
 <option value="19">Santa Cruz</option>
 <option value="20">Santa Fe</option>
 <option value="21">Santiago del Estero</option>
 <option value="22">Tierra del Fuego</option>
 <option value="23">Tucumán</option>
 <option value="24">Ciudad Autónoma de Buenos Aires</option>
```

But I can't fill the select with generated options. Thanks.

Comment: select belongs to current selected dropdown, use the 2nd dropdown for slector, by id

Answer (score 0):

The `$(this).parent()` stored in your `select` variable will refer to the parent `div` of `.country` tag what means when you try `selec.find(".province")` the selector will not find the element since there's no element with the `province` class inside the div, What I suggest is to target the select with the `id` (that should be unique) using :

```
var select = $("#province");
```

Then replace :

```
select.find('.province').html(" ");
select.find('.province').append(op);
```

By :

```
select.html(op);
```

Comment: Zakaria!!! in general front it's not my favorite thing and i just know  a little bit of ajax, but you are a genius!!!! this solution worked perfect!!! thanks a lot!! Now i'll try to replicate this to the others selects. Thanks Again!!!